# Why are there 2 balls in electrostatic generator electrodes?

Tags: electrostatics

[image]
Why are there 2 balls (a smaller and a bigger one) on each electrode of the Wimshurst machine instead of just one ?

Answer (score 1):

> Significantly longer sparks can be obtained by the addition of a
>   smaller ball attached to the positive terminal. This increases the
>   electric field around the positive terminal, forcing the ionization of
>   the air to start at the positive side of the gap, instead of at the
>   negative side, as happens with a symmetrical gap. The positive
>   ionization forms a nice plume-like structure (that can be seen in the
>   dark) pointing away from the positive terminal, that easily gets
>   connected to the diffuse corona that the negative terminal emits

source : https://www.coe.ufrj.br/~acmq/whyhow.html